# How can you convert a black and white image into color using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

Is there a better way in Photoshop to convert a black & white image into color other than just selecting the area and fill with color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using Hue saturation u can change the black&white picture to colour

select the area u want to change 
 click the adjustments in the bottom of the layer panel and select hue&saturation
by these u can change the colour
dont forget to check the colorize

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no color information in the image, only tonal information. Unfortunately, the best I could suggest is to make your black and white image a multiply layer and paint the colors on a layer(s) underneath.